# How to find if a tag exists in deep nested xml using xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an xml like

```
<a>
 <b>
  <c>
  </c>
  <c>
   <d>xyz</d>
  </c>
 </b>
 <b>
  <c>
  </c>
  <c>
  </c>
 </b>
 <b>
  <c>
  </c>
 </b>
</a>
```

I want to check if tag 'd' exist or not and if it has value xyz? How do i do it?

Currently I am doing it by using nested for each loops three times. Is there any better/direct way?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do this expression...

```
<xsl:if test="//d[. = 'xyz']">
```

This will work wherever you are positioned in the XML. If you only want to check descendants of the current node, do this

```
<xsl:if test=".//d[. = 'xyz']">
```

Which is shorthand for this...

```
<xsl:if test="descendant-or-self::d[. = 'xyz']">
```

Comment: Just a reminder that this can be a very expensive operation in terms of performance, so you should only use it when you have to.

Comment: @Tim C is the number of '/' in the test="//..."  always two or does it depend on the level of the tag 'd' ( or how deep it is located inside the parent tag ) ?

Comment: It is always two to search anywhere in the document.